# How to not translate hot keys with QActions in Qt?

Tags: qt, translate

In my current project we are using Qt and its translation system for making the GUI localized for many languages.

My main problem is the translation of hot keys.

When the user opens the main menu he can see all menu items and hot keys associated with them. This information is stored within QAction. When we change the language (for example to arabic) the user can see the translated menu item texts and its hot key will also be translated. But I don't want the hot key to be translated.

I did some research on this problem and found the flag "translatable" for shortcuts in QtDesigner. But this flag did not help because it's needed only when we want to add this shortcut to our translate system, for example different hot keys for the same action for different languages.

The main problem in that is that Qt gets the string for any hot key by using [`QKeySquence::toString()`](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qkeysequence.html#toString). But this method automatically translates "Ctrl", "Del", "Alt" and other words, using QShortcut context. And all QShortcut translations are stored in the default `qm` files in Qt that we have included in our project.

So how to *not translate* hot keys?

Comment: Just to be sure: Do you always want the hot keys in English language, no matter which language is currently active? (So *always* show for example `Ctrl+C`)

Comment: Yes, I do. It is what i need.

Comment: Hahaha, I'm having the opposite problem... I want my hotkeys translated.